# How to open a new page as if a link was clicked when you scroll to the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I was checking out this site and thought it would be a cool little trick to learn. When you scroll to the bottom, it opens their portfolio page in the same window/tab. I would love to do something exactly like this. How is it done? I can't really see much with developer tools as the page keeps changing when the coded bit goes into view. I gather it's some javascript, which I'm mostly unfamiliar with, but definitely something I could learn/tweak a snippet of. Please let me know, as I'd also like to use this on a wordpress site like they do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by some jQuery or javascript tricks

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) window.location = "portfolio.html";
});
```

or by JS

```js
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
       alert("Do your fancy stuff here, like redirect");
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay thank you, and please forgive the ignorance, but where exactly do I specify the height in these examples?

Comment: @Harris you dont have to mention the heights. It will be  calculated by its own using window dom